# Fixing Extra Fields in Dataframe Exceeding Field Length of CSV

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I created a new csv concatenated based on other csv's delimited by \t. Most rows have successfully been mapped to its associated cell in Excel, except the few that exceed the number of fields.

```
b'Skipping line 4046: expected 39 fields, saw 41\nSkipping line 7924: expected 39 fields, saw 40\n'
```

I want to fix the rows that have all its data in one cell by splitting them and mapping them to columns. The last column can keep the extra data for the row.

Row 80 is an example of a "bad" row to be fixed:

[image: Row 80 is an example of a "bad" row to be fixed]

```
path = r'C:\Users\afsulta\.spyder-py3\ISG\master_reten_isg.csv'
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
csv_files = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'csv' and 'reten_isg' in f] # identify reten_isg files
master = pd.DataFrame()

for file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True, sep='\t', header=0, encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False, delimiter='\t', error_bad_lines=False) # Ignores errors and corrupt data
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() # remove whitespace from columns
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x) # strip leading and trailing whitespace from rows
    master = master.append(df, ignore_index=True) # concatenate each isg file to master
```

How would I write code to combine the extra fields into the last cell, if the row's entries exceed the field length? Is this the best way to fix this issue? What are other solutions, and what is the best solution if possible?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you have few extra columns in some files which are causing the issue.
You can make use of **pandas.concat**. Attached is a image of snippet of what i am saying.

[image]